# multiple log files being generated

Tags: java, logging

I have written an application wherein I am downloading email and logging details in a file called my.log using a filehandler.

FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("my.log",5242880,1,true);
loggerObject.addHandler(handler);

Although the logging is happening correctly, multiple files like my.log.1 ,my.log.2 etc. are being generated in the same directory .They arent temporary and remain there even after the program stops executing.

Why are they being generated and how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the [documentation for `FileHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html)  and you will see a number is added for file conflict resolution.  If there is an existing file, the `%u` marker in the pattern will be replaced with the next available number.  If there is no `%u` marker then it is added to the end of the filename.

To avoid this, you need to make sure you close the previously opened file when you have finished writing to it.